# Undefined variable JS AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, get, frontend

I'm trying to display Objects received through JSON arrays, communicating in AJAX with my backend server (Django). All the AJAX/Communication part works well. I want to display the received objects in a chatbox.

[This is my arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgBui.png)

However, my code gets undefined variables when displaying the Arrays.
HTML:

```
    <div id="display"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/checkview",
            success: function go(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
                for (var model in response.models_to_return)
                {
                    var temp="<div class='container darker'><b>"+ model.user_id +"</b><p>"+ model.room +"</p><span class='time-left'>"+ model.datetime +"</span></div>";
                    $("#display").append(temp);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                //alert('An error occured')
            }
        });
    },1000);
    })
</script>
```

[Front-end ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Z1k.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach for json array loop.

Here is code.

```
response.models_to_return.forEach(function(model, index) {
    console.log(model);
});
```

Full exmaple:

```
const models = [
{fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25},
{fname:"John2", lname:"Doe2", age:26},
{fname:"John3", lname:"Doe3", age:27}
];

models.forEach(function(model) {
    console.log(model.fname);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to loop over the elements of an array. `for...in` should instead be used for iterating over properties.

```js
for (const model of response.models_to_return)
```